# Sort an array of objects by date and section them accordingly in TableView

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

I have an app that contains allows the user to upload a meal to firebase for later viewing and I want to display those meals sorted by the date they were recorded and sectioned accordingly in TableView in a descending order (by date).

The Meal object is defined below

```
class Meal: NSObject, Codable {

var id: String?
var foodname: String?
var quantity: Float!
var brandName: String?
var quantityType: String?
var calories: Float!
var date: Date?
}
```

And my TableView currently looks like this

```
class MealsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var databaseController: DatabaseProtocol?
var sections = Dictionary<String, Array<Meal>>()
var sortedSections = [String]()

var listOfMeals = [Meal]() {
    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    databaseController = appDelegate.databaseController
    let accountsRef = databaseController?.getAccountsRef()

    accountsRef?.document(SingletonAccount.shared.userEmail).collection("meals")
        .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Error retrieving all meals!")
            }else{
                do{
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents
                    {
                        let currentMeal = Meal()
                        let data = try! document.data()
                        currentMeal.id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
                        currentMeal.brandName = data["brandName"] as? String ?? ""
                        currentMeal.calories = data["calories"] as? Float ?? 0.0
                        let parsingDate = data["date"] as! Timestamp
                        currentMeal.date = parsingDate.dateValue()
                        currentMeal.foodname = data["foodname"] as? String
                        currentMeal.quantity = data["quantity"] as? Float
                        currentMeal.quantityType = data["quantityType"] as? String
                        print(currentMeal.date)
                        self.listOfMeals.append(currentMeal)
                     }

                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }




}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return listOfMeals.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foodCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = listOfMeals[indexPath.row].foodname
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(listOfMeals[indexPath.row].calories) + "kJ"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.secondaryLabel
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    return cell
}
```

I have also tried to use the code below to try and sort the objects by date but it doesn't work.

```
                self.listOfMeals.sort { (meal1, meal2) -> Bool in
                return (meal1.date!.compare(meal2.date!))
            }
```

I tried other methods posted here but they all don't seem to work

Comment: Be careful with getDocuments as it will read every single meal in your entire database. Over time that could be tens of thousands of meals and trying to load them all in at once and then sort could overwhelm the device (and also be really slooow). Much better to add a limit to read in a smaller section of data. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `compare` method is not what you need since it will return a [ComparisonResult](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/comparisonresult) instance between the two dates. Also if the dates are optionals, don't force cast them otherwise you app might crash when one of them is nil.

```
self.listOfMeals.sort { meal1, meal2 -> Bool in
    guard let meal1Date = meal1.date, let meal2Date = meal2.date else { return false }
    return meal1Date < meal2Date
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort and group your objects in one go you can use `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` together with the sorting

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let nilDate = Date.distantPast

let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: listOfMeals.sorted(by: { ($0.date ?? nilDate) < ($1.date ?? nilDate) }),
                         by: { calendar.startOfDay(for: $0.date ?? nilDate) })
```

Below is a simple test case

```
struct Meal: CustomStringConvertible {
    var id: String?
    var date: Date?

    var description: String {
        get {
            let dateString = date == nil ? "nil" : String(describing: date!)
            return "\(id!) \(dateString)"
        }
    }
}

let day = 24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0
var listOfMeals = [
    Meal(id: "a", date: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5000)),
    Meal(id: "b", date: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -5000)),
    Meal(id: "c", date: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: (day + 5000.0))),
    Meal(id: "d", date: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: day)),
    Meal(id: "e", date: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -day)),
    Meal(id: "f", date: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -(day - 5000.0))),
    Meal(id: "g", date: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)),
    Meal(id: "h", date: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -2 * day)),
]
```

Comment: How would I specify the number of sections in table from and access the date elements from grouped? Sorry im not familiar with dictionaries yet

Comment: A dictionary has a property keys, which is an array so you can access the `count` property, `grouped.keys.count`

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding but it seems the question asks how to read in meals sorted descending by date.

You are not going to want to read in EVERY MEAL as shown in other answers to then sort them in memory as that could be an overwhelming amount of data. So note that you can add [limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) to my code as well only show meals for the month of June, or only 10 meals at a time, for example.

Let Firestore do the work for you. Here's the code to read in your meal objects sorted descending.

```
func readMealsSortedDesc() {
    let meals = self.db.collection("meals") //self.db points to my Firestore
    meals.order(by: "date", descending: true).getDocuments(completion: { snapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }

        for doc in documents {
            let docId = doc.documentID
            let name = doc.get("foodname") as? String ?? "No Food Name"
            let date = doc.get("date") as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp()
            print(docId, name, date.dateValue())
        }
    })
}
```

and if there were three meals in June (adding a limit for just June), one on the 1st, one on the 15th and one on the 30th, here's the output

```
meal_2 Hot Dog 2020-06-30 04:00:00 +0000
meal_1 Burger 2020-06-15 04:00:00 +0000
meal_0 Pizza 2020-06-01 04:00:00 +0000
```

I don't know specifically how you want to organize the data but you should have a dataSource array that contains objects that represent the sections and also hold the section child data. Something like this

```
var myDailyMealsArray = [DailyMealStruct]()

struct DailyMealStruct {
    var sectionTitle = "this would be a string of the date"
    var mealNameArray = [String]()
}
```

So as your data is read from Firebase, add it to the appropriate DailyMealStruct object (all meals from 2020-06-01 in that object, then all meals for 2020-06-02 in that object etc)

From there, your sections are the # of objects in the myDailyMealsArray, and the child data is from the mealNameArray within each object.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.myDailyMealsArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let title = self.myDailyMealsArray[section].sectionTitle
    return title
}
```